# SQL80001: Incorrect syntax near 'SELECT'

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to create a Table in a database on Visual Studio 2012.
I think the language it's T-SQL.

It's not my work and I know very little about SQL, so I'm sorry if it is a very easy or stupid question.

I'm trying to import in the table (Presence) a column (Name) from another table (People) with all the values inside.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Presence]
(
[Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
SELECT Name FROM People
)
```

It gives me this error

`SQL80001: Incorrect syntax near 'SELECT'`

I searched online but i didn't find the same error (there are other things instead of 'select' and the solutions didn't work for me)

Could you help me? Thank you very much :)

Comment: You need to create the table first, then Insert from Select.

Comment: Also when you create the table, make sure you include all the columns you want in that table (right now you only have ID as integer and that's not going to work if you plan on also inserting name values you need at least 1 more column).

Comment: Ok, maybe I've understood, I will try, thanks!